# Smoothing issues in $\left( \int_0^1 f(x) dx \right) \left( \int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(x)} dx \right) \le \frac{(m+M)^2}{4mM}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, analysis, inequality

> Let $f: [0,1] \to [m, M]$ where $m,M\in \mathbb{R}^+$. Prove that
> $$\left( \int_0^1 f(x) dx \right) \left( \int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(x)} dx \right) \le \frac{(m+M)^2}{4mM}.$$

I know a rigorous solution now: it is

\begin{align*}
 \left( \int_0^1 f(x)\, \mathrm{d}x \right) \left( \int_0^1 \frac{1}{f(x)}\, \mathrm{d} x \right)
 &= \frac{M}{m} \left( \int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{M}\, \mathrm{d}x \right) \left( \int_0^1 \frac{m}{f(x)}\, \mathrm{d} x \right)\\
 &\le \frac{M}{m}\cdot \frac14\left(\int_0^1 \frac{f(x)}{M}\, \mathrm{d}x + \int_0^1 \frac{m}{f(x)}\, \mathrm{d} x\right)^2\\
 &= \frac{M}{m}\cdot \frac14\left(\int_0^1 \left(\frac{f(x)}{M} + \frac{m}{f(x)}\right)\, \mathrm{d}x\right)^2\\
 &\le \frac{M}{m}\cdot \frac14\left(\int_0^1 \left(1 + \frac{m}{M}\right)\, \mathrm{d}x\right)^2\\
 &= \frac{(m + M)^2}{4mM}
\end{align*}
where we use
$\frac{u}{M} + \frac{m}{u}
\le 1 + \frac{m}{M}$ for all $u\in [m, M]$ (*Note*: $1 + \frac{m}{M} - \frac{u}{M} - \frac{m}{u} = \frac{(u - m)(M - u)}{Mu}$).

But I wonder what is wrong with the following solution (which works if I replace $\int_0^1 f(x) dx$ by $\frac{a_1+\cdots+a_n}{n}$ where $a_i\in [m,M]$, which is a discrete version of the ineq)

One can show that $g(x)=ax+b/x$ is maximized when $x\in \{m,M\}$ so we can assume $f(j)\in \{m,M\}$. Let $h(x)=\frac{f(x)-m}{M-m}$ and $k=\int_0^1 h(x) dx$ Then $\int_0^1 f(x)dx = m + (M-m)\int_0^1 h(x)dx = m+(M-m)k$ and $\int_0^1 f(x)^{-1} dx = (1-k)/m + k/M$ and we can see their product is maximized when $k=\frac 12$.

I think it has issues but I'm not sure where.

Comment: If I understood correctly you used $\int_0^1\frac{m}{f(x)}\;dx\leq\frac{m}{M}$ in your rigorous solution. But this inequality  does not hold in general, I think. Can you clarify that? E.g. for $f(x)=1+x^2$ you get $m=1,M=2$ but $\int_0^1\frac{m}{f(x)}\;dx=\frac{\pi}{4}\not\leq\frac12=\frac{m}{M}$

Comment: @ThomasPreu I did not use that. I used the identity $xy \le \frac{(x+y)^2}{4}$ in the first inequality where $x=\int_0^1 f(x)/M dx$. Then I used the inequality $f(x)/M + m/f(x) \le 1+\frac mM$. Hope this clears it up.

Comment: OK. I thought you would consider each of $\frac{f(x)}{M}$ and $\frac{m}{f(x)}$ separately. But now it is clear. Everything's fine.

Comment: Alright, now I would like some explanation for why the "smoothing" solution is not rigorous. My gut feeling tells me it has problems, but I don't know where.

Comment: @KaiWang You may give the (more) detailed version of the "smoothing" solution.

Comment: I have a rough sense of why it doesn't work now, but for the discrete version, the one with $(a_1+\cdots+a_n)(a_1^{-1}+\cdots+a_n^{-1})$, one can fix all variables except for one, call $a_i$, and show this expression is maximized when $a_i\in \{m,M\}$. I tried generalizing that to the integral version of the inequality. I've talked to some friends, which basically changes $f(j)$ one at a time (say $f(0), f(1/e), f(1/\sqrt{2}).. $and they said I should study real analysis to see why it fails. Apparently it does work when $f$ is continuous (in fact, should be fine if $f$ is Riemann integrable).

Comment: @KaiWang Your approach looks nice. Your comment is clearer than the OP, I think. For example, $g(x)=ax+b/x$, later you let $g(x) = 1$, I think you may change one of these two $g(x)$.

Comment: Okay, I've replaced that with $h(x)=\frac{f(x)-m}{M-m}$

Comment: @KaiWang How did you get $\int_0^1 f(x)^{-1} dx = (1-k)/m + k/M$?

Comment: That was when $h(x) \in \{0,1\}$. In general, LHS is at most RHS in the above equation, which might be provable via generalized Karamata? Let $k(x)=\frac 1x$ then $k$ is convex. Let $t(x)=M$ if $x\le k$ and $t(x)=m$ otherwise. Can we use Karamata to prove that $\int_0^1 k(f(x)) dx \le \int_0^1 k(t(x))$ since $\int_0^q t(x) dx \ge \int_0^q f(x) dx$ for all $0\le q\le 1$ and $\int_0^1 t(x) dx = \int_0^1 f(x) dx$

Comment: It's called Schweitzer's inequality .

Comment: @KaiWang You need to give more details to make things clear. In general, $h(x) \in \{0, 1\}$ is not the case for general $f(x)$. You said $k=\int_0^1 h(x) dx$. Now you said "Let $k(x) = \frac{1}{x}$, then $k$ is convex". Are the two $k$ related to each other?

Comment: Nevermind I do see why it doesn't work. Sorry for mixing up the variable names :(

Comment: @KaiWang Nice. Hope to see your finding.